# Book involving a global race to reach a distress beacon from an alien ship in space

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I’m looking for the title. I think it was a series of books with an Asian-like title.

The plot involved:

- Futuristic space travel.
- A global race to get to a distress beacon from an alien ship in space.
- A venting system to cool the ship's plasma drive.
- More than one country arrived at the alien ship at the same time, and there was a standoff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Geez. It was old when I read it about 5 years ago. I think it may have been from the 90s. I realize that’s not helpful.

Comment: The title of the book was the name of the ship I think. And it was an Asian name.

Comment: I thought it had rendezvous in the title but it’s not rendezvous with Rama

Comment: The alien ship had an Asian name? Presumably, that was a name given to it by humans?

Comment: _[Saturn Run](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24611668-saturn-run)_ (2015) by John Sandford has a similar premise. It apparently describes an engine cooling system as well, although I've not seen any mention of a distress beacon.

Comment: It's not Iain M Banks' *[Excession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excession)* is it? Story features race to get to alien artifact, standoff of some sort, pushing engines to their limits (though plasma??).

Comment: @Deb - There aren't that many 'rendezvous's in fiction; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=rendezvous&type=Fiction+Titles